# How to solve buildah run error: container not known?

Tags: docker, containers, devops, podman, buildah

So I build container using buildah bud:

```
buildah bud -t ${imageFullName()} -f ${componentName}/DockerfileTests ${buildArgsStr} ${componentName}
```

But then, when I try to run a command inside this container:

```
buildah run ${componentName} -- python3 -m pytest src/test_models.py
```

it returns `error reading build container: container not known` . How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, my first command make an image, not a container.
To create a container from this image, i have to run command:

```
buildah from ${imageFullName()}
```

Now, when you've created a container you can look for it's name by using a command which displays all containers that are avalable now:

```
buildah containers
```

And after getting the name of the container you can successfully run:

```
buildah run ${containerName} -- ...your command...
```